# WM_CTLCOLOREDIT not sent

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi

I am trying to catch WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message withen WndProc but the control (derived from TextBox) don't send it.

```
    public class TestTB: TextBox
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case 0x133 // WM_CTLCOLOREDIT
               :
                    {
                        var w = m.WParam;
                        // i need to do somthing here but WM_CTLCOLOREDIT never sent.
                        break;
                    }
            }
            base.WndProc(m);
        }
    }
```

According to [WM_CTLCOLOREDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms932325(v=msdn.10)) documentation

> Read-only or disabled edit controls do not send the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT
>   message; instead, they send the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message.

but I didn't set the textbox as readonly or disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms932325(v=msdn.10)) (and [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms932356(v=msdn.10))) will be sent to the TextBox's **parent window**, not to the TextBox itself.  This is documented behavior:

[WM_CTLCOLOREDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms932325(v=msdn.10))

> This message **notifies the parent window** of an edit control when the control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, the **parent window** can use the specified device context handle to set the text and background colors of the edit control.

[WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms932356(v=msdn.10))

> This message is **sent to the parent window** of a static control when the control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, the **parent window** can use the specified device context handle to set the text and background colors of the static control.

So you need to override the WndProc of the TextBox's parent control instead.